# Need to copy the text inside an <a> tag and move it inside a specific <div>

Tags: jquery

I have this piece of code:

```
<li class="selected"><a href="/AmIACandidate.html">Am I a Candidate?</a></li>
```

I need to grab the text "Am I a Candidate?" from inside the  tag and move it inside a specific div tag.

```
<div id="sideNavHeader"> --Copy needs to go here-- </div>
```

I can copy the whole

but can't seem to figure out how to grab just the text. I'm using it to dynamically create a title to a side nav on my site.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tobias Cohen's selector was much better than mine you should use:

```
$('#sideNavHeader').html($('li.selected a').html());
```

instead of my original code:

```
$('#sideNavHeader').html($('li.selected').children('a').html());
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
$('#sideNavHeader').text($('li.selected a').text());
```